# Noble map pack for Halo Reach is not showing up in game

Tags: halo-reach

I downloaded the Noble map pack when it was first released and although Xbox live says that I have downloaded it, its not showing up in game under the DLC section of matchmaking. Its only showing the new one which I haven't purchased yet.

Any ideas where it could be hiding? I have downloaded it for a second time to see if it made any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last playlist update (pushed out on 3rd May 2011) the Noble and Defiant map packs were merged: [Halo Forum Update Changelist Post](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=59904504).

This means that the Defiant playlist that appears under the DLC does actually include the Noble maps as well. Unfortunately the Defiant map pack DLC is required to be able to use this playlist. One solution for you could be to purchase the Defiant map pack, however, the Noble map pack is not a requirement for this playlist, which means that you will only get Noble maps on the voting screen when all of the players have the Noble map pack too.

If you don't want to buy the Defiant map pack, then the only other option for you is to use the normal playlists. The Noble maps have been integrated into the normal playlists according to the [November 30th 2010 Changlist](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=53673689). This means that you should theoretically still be able to play the Noble maps, however these will only appear on the voting screen when all of the connected players also have the Noble map pack, but as you have probably noticed, the chances of this happening are pretty slim.

This quote is from the [Bungie.net Noble Map Pack FAQ](http://www.bungie.net/News/content.aspx?type=topnews&link=NMPFAQ):

> Many other playlists will contain DLC
>   maps as well, but since you are not
>   gated from entry to these playlists by
>   having DLC, you could match with
>   people who don’t have the maps. If
>   that happens, you will not get them as
>   voting options for that session.

You may be able to improve the chances of you playing one of the Noble maps by using the playlists that require less players. I think that if all connected players do have the Noble DLC, then at least one Noble map will show up in the voting options.

Comment: There are a number of other players that have raised this on the Halo forums but I couldn't find a consistent answer there. If you're interested you can read some discussions [here](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=59930640&postRepeater1-p=1), [here](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=60105840&postRepeater1-p=1), and [here](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=60240039).

Comment: You may also find [this forum post](http://www.bungie.net/Forums/posts.aspx?postID=60279183) interesting. It propses several solutions to the problem you are having, but whether or not any of the solutions are implemented is up to Bungie.

Answer (score 0):

You may be affected by an issue related to the number of content items you can have for each game.  See this [Bungie.net](http://www.bungie.net/News/Blog.aspx?mode=tags&tag=41) post which states:

> Turns out that there's currently a
>   technical issue tied to the number of
>   Marketplace Content items you can have
>   active for Halo: Reach at any one
>   given time (this does not include
>   Saved Games, Screenshots, or Saved
>   Films). Right now, you can only have a
>   total of three content items
>   simultaneously active. Items that fit
>   the bill include pre-order bonus or
>   retailer exclusive armor, map packs,
>   or your Bungie Pro confirmation.

While this article talks about the Defiant map pack the issue could equally affect the Noble map pack since it's an issue with XBox rather than a specific piece of DLC.

One way to determine for sure whether the maps are accessible is to go to Custom Games and try to select one of the maps from the Noble Map Pack - if you can't do this then you are most likely affected by the above issue and will have to take action to address it as detailed in Bungie's post.